# joomla getting notices when try to run my project

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

When I am trying to run my joomla project it give me list of notice with some warning.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/gms/libraries/framework/Joomla/Registry/Registry.php on line 419
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/gms/libraries/framework/Joomla/Registry/Registry.php on line 421
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/gms/libraries/framework/Joomla/Registry/Registry.php on line 424
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/gms/libraries/framework/Joomla/Registry/Registry.php on line 428

Dont't know how to solve it

Comment: Which version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on here.  This question is likely to be closed as "Off-topic: why isn't my code working?"  Are you aware that there is a dedicated Q&A site exclusively for Joomla support? It is [joomla.se] and it is one of the menu items in your Joomla site's backend/administrator Help menu.  Perhaps post your Joomla questions there to speak to an audience that has a more intimate understanding of Joomla.

Comment: I am using joomla 3.8.10 
wget https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-8-10/Joomla_3-8-10-Stable-Full_Package.zip